# How to get a list of event created by a user in facebook using JS sdk?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using graph API to get a list of Events created by a user who got authenticated using FB.login API.

I have a get friend API that seems to work for my but getting event is not working.

```
        //function that gets the list of friends
        function getFriends() {
            FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
                //console.log(response);
            });
        }

        //function that gets the list of events for the user.
        function getEvents() {
            FB.api('/me/events',function(data) { 
                if (data && !data.error) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your user access token needs the `user_events` permission.

Comment: Oh sorry I should have updated it I am login with that permission